# Formio select URL custom headers issue

Tags: angular, formio

I am using angular CLI on the front-end side and I am using angular-formio for dynamic for building. but I am facing an issue in the passing of custom headers in API.
I created a form with select dynamic select dropdown and select data source type `URL`. but I am unable to pass header value which is currently stored in my local storage.

[image]

when I use localStorage.getItem function in the headers value field, it takes it as a string and passes as it is in API headers.
I found this [link](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/wiki/JavaScript-API#plugin-api) for passing custom headers, but this is a javascript method that I can't use in angular CLI application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got the solution by my own which is

in response header area

provide a key 'key' and in value section call a localStorage Function like this.

```
{{localStorage.getItem('key')}}
```

now it will pass your custom headers as you want to pass.